# How do I revert Windows 11 store apps to their factory version?

Tags: windows, software-update, bloatware

I mean like you can on Android, that is when you go to your apps list on Android and tap on an app, you have an option to "unistall app updates" and revert the software to its factory version. You can do this of course only for system apps / preinstalled / and bloatware.

Can you do this on a Windows device too? (Without having to factory reset the OS) There are a bunch of system apps that I accidentally updated, and since I can't uninstall them, I want to at least know how to delete the update only (as I know the factory version will still remain on your machine, it doesn't get deleted with the update, all this for an eventual factory OS reset's sake).

And, in case it can be done on Win11, is there a way to do this on Windows 10 too?

Comment: The UWP App updates seem relatively benign.  What has gone wrong that you need to uninstall the updates. I do not think you can uninstall UWP updates (UWP = Universal Windows Platform)..   App repair usually installs the newest version.

Comment: John, I just don't want to burden my machine, since the updates for a system preinstalled app will sit just right on top of the factory version. Ergo the factory version WILL not be deleted, so you'll have two versions on your machine, the factory one and the current update. I mean, on android you can uninstall app updates, why couldn't you do that on Windows too?

Comment: Windows is not Android. You don't revert bloatware - you delete it.

Comment: The UWP app updates are benign and on my Windows 11 machines have ZERO effect on performance.  The updates do not produce two versions. I have not seen that at all.

Comment: Android app updates are benign too, but you can revert them.
They do produce two versions, when you reset your Windows OS it will reinstall the factory version.

Comment: I looked at the App Folder with Tree Size.  It is only 2.5 GB and most Apps do not have duplicates. Only a few do. So something is different in your machine to my Windows 11 machines (now nearly a year old).

Comment: The feature you describe does NOT exist on Windows. If installed the installed UWP applications will be updated, once updated, it’s not possible to revert the update.

Comment: John, those few are the preinstalled apps I was talking about. The ones that don't are the UWP apps that you chose to install yourself.

Comment: It is a real letdown that it's not possible to do this in windows, it should be a superior OS to Android.

Comment: The ones that don't are the UWP apps that you chose to install yourself.  - No. I do not install any UWP apps myself. I use the Desktop version if I need the App (iTunes for example).